# how do i get rid of this "none" message in my basic forum?

Tags: python, bottle, forum

I'm completely new to the bottle framework and its methods. As a homework, my constructor wanted me to build a basic forum which should be able to accomplish simple posting, deleting, sorting, etc. messages.

Just, post a message, delete it by inserting its number and go back to the messages page. You will see a "None" message.

This is the part of the site that deletes the message:

```
@bottle.route("/erasedlogs" , method="POST")   
def erased_logs():    
   global message_depo
   integer=bottle.request.POST.get('number')
   del message_depo[int(integer)]
   i=0
   while i < len(message_depo):
       content=content + '<p> '+ message_depo[i]+ ' :comment' + str(i) + '</p> \n' 
       i=i+1
    
   content=content + '<p> <a style="color:red" href="/message">See current messages.</a></p> \n '
```

And this is the page which reserves the messages:

```
@bottle.route("/message", method="ANY")
def get_message():
    global message_depo
    message=bottle.request.POST.get('message')
    time_message=datetime.datetime.now()
    message_log=str(message)+ " = " + str(time_message)
    message_depo.append(message_log)
    i=0
    while i< len(message_depo):
        content=content + ' <p> '+ message_depo[i]+ ' <strong>:comment</strong> ' + str(i) + '</p> \n'
```

When I hit the link "see current messages" in the first block of code it creates a meaningless (at least for me) "None" message.

Could someone simply explain why it happens and how I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you return anything from your functions ?

Comment: The `None` appears to be coming from `bottle.request.POST.get('message')` when `'message' not in bottle.request.POST`.

Comment: In both of the functions, there is a return value such as :     'return htmlify(body,content)'  -----htmlify and body are just basic design tools, so i didn't add them to the code because of its length.

Comment: How would i get rid of it then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning any content.  In both of your functions, you need to add this line:

```
return content
```